# Check backup recovery points via powershell - windows host backed up in an azure recovery vault

Tags: powershell, azure

I would like to check recovery points for an on-premise windows host backed up with the Microsoft Azure Backup Agent.

I can access the Backup Container like this:

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext 
$ct = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType Windows -BackupManagementType MARS
```

I would expect the next steps would be to use

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType MARS .....
```

and then

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint ...
```

But [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723305.aspx) for Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem says

> -BackupManagementType
>   Specifies the Backup management type. 
>   **Currently, the only supported value is AzureVM**.

So now the question is:

Is there some (other) way to list the recovery points for an on-premise windows host backed up to an azure recovery vault using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the documentation you linked to, and it looks like MARS is a valid value for the BackupManagementType paramater.  Your first command looks correct:

```
$BackupItem = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType MARS .....
```

Then get the Recovery Point in whatever date range you want:

```
$EndDate = Get-Date #Today's date
$StartDate = $EndDate.AddDays(-7) 
$RP=Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $item –StartDate $StartDate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $EndDate.ToUniversalTime()
```

I'm not sure which command you would then use to restore the host, but I'm guessing you would just pass in the Recovery Point ID as the ResourceId like this:

```
–ResourceId $RP[0].ID
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6595) at the Azure PowerShell repo for this. *Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem* requires parameter *-WorkloadType* which currently does not accept an on-premise value like *Windows* or *WindowsServer* which would be associated with *-BackupManagementType MARS*.

I would highly encourage anyone impacted by this go voice their support for a commit under that issue.